# desktop computer with Intel core 2 duo

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-office, intel-core2

Computer Specs: Intel Core 2 Duo with 2 GB RAM, 250 GB HDD, Vista 32 bit OS. Main usage is email, normal word resume updating and internet browsing. Is this configuration good enough for these tasks? I don't have budget for i.... series machines.
Please see the definition of Good Enough below.

**EDIT**

By Good enough means, the audience is my wife and kids, who use it for stuff like creating word documents, using facebook, creating picture in paint, play kids's game in the browser etc.. And I don't need super sonic speed, but at the same time, it should not take 10 minutes to login to account.

Comment: Shopping recommendations are considered off topic, sorry. Please read our [FAQ] and [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: @slhcs strange.. This is not shopping question. I'm not asking about any specific brand here. This should not be closed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but *"I'm planning to buy … is this good enough?"* is definitely a shopping recommendation question. If you read the blog post I've linked to you, the reason behind this is explained in further detail. The question is much too localized to your situation (specific hardware), and not even constructive since there's no definition for "good enough" (see Hennes' answer which unfortunately is the only true answer for this question).

Comment: This is still too localized, sorry. If you want to ask about what to buy or if what you plan to buy is good enough, drop by [chat], please. There are always people around who love to help in these cases.

Answer (score 2):

Good enough has no clear answer.

Will you be able to use it for that? Yes.
Is it capable of doing those task at a decent speed: My opinion: Yes.

**However** I would like to tell this little anecdote to make a point:

I had a 'decent speed' computer. I liked it.
When I used my sister computer and got home my own rig felt nice and fast.
Then we got new computer at work, much faster. Now when I came home if felt frustratingly slow.

The point I am trying to make it that it will work, but if it will work well enough can't be answered.

Comment: Like the anecdote! as soon as you use someone elses faster computer... yours seems slower than ever!

Answer (score 1):

It will run those things fine. It wont be the fanciest or fastest thing in the world but for someone on a budget it will fulfill your needs.

I prefer windows 7 to Vista but for the average user (from your question I would put you in that category) Vista will work

Answer (score 0):

instead of vista prefer windows 7. Hard disk min. 500gb. rest is good.

vista don't have support and have compatibility issue .

Comment: 500GB is WAY overkill for everyday web browsing and email users.

Comment: Aye. If you do not store movies or **lots** of music then a 60GG SSD works just fine. A 250GB (four times that size) HDD is more than enough.

Comment: i always prefer this if i don't know about the user. But it is up to user how much memory he wants.if he thinks that 250 will be enough than ok,take 250. But later purchase will be much costlier then current.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good configuration for the basic tasks you want to accomplish. In my opinion, look for a system with another OS as Vista is not that great, but that's just an opinion. Windows 7 is great or even XP.

Comment: Support for Windows XP will end in April 2014.

Comment: Wow, good to know. I don't use it anymore but still preferred it over Vista.

Answer (score 0):

fwiw, I do far, far more than that with the exact same specs. When I'm on the road, I bring this one with me. I run a server in a virtual manager with 3 browsers open and an editor. Obviously I'm a web developer.